# How to control respond_to based on variable in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### The dilemma

I'm using a `before_filter` in my controller that restricts access to admins. However, I want to allow access public access to some methods based on request `format`. See the `index` method to understand what I'm talking about.

### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # ...

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user])
  end

  def superuser_required
    redirect_to login_path unless current_user.superuser?
  end


end
```

### items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :superuser_required
  layout 'superuser'

  def index
    @items = Item.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js # I want public to have access to this
    end
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  # remaining controller methods
  # ...

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Way easier than I expected

2 days later

```
class FoosController < ActiveRecord::Base

  # use :except to open `show` action for public js access
  before_filter :superuser_required, :except => 'index'

  # before_filter does not apply here
  def index
    @foos = Foo.all

    respond_to do |format|

      # restrict behavior on html access for superusers
      format.html do
        superuser_required  # functions same as before_filter
      end

      # unrestricted on js access for public but only shows foo.id and foo.name
      format.js do
        render :text => @foo.to_json(:only => [:id, :name])
      end

    end
  end

  # restricted to superuser per before_filter
  def new
    @foo = Foo.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  # restricted to superuser per before_filter
  def show
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

end
```

Either I totally missed something when I was learning about `respond_to` or my original question was completely incoherent. I just read it again, though,  and it still seems like this only (and most) appropriate way to address my issue.

Surprisingly, I couldn't really find any examples of this kind of behavior on the web either. Oh well. Now I know more about `respond_to`, right?

Answer (score 3):

Filters have access to the `request` object which has a [`format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Request.html#M000700) method you can use to obtain the request format. Change your before filter so that if the format is JavaScript then the request processing is allowed to proceed. Something like:

```
def superuser_required
  return true if request.format == Mime::JS
  redirect_to login_path unless current_user.superuser?
end
```

Comment: Technically, the `superuser_required` method is defined in `ApplicationController` because it's shared for a lot of my controllers. I updated my post to show this. I have several `js` format actions that are restricted to admins only, so I don't think modifying `superuser_required` is a safe bet. The `respond_to { |f| f.js }` in `ItemsController#index` should be the **only** action response that is opened to public.

Comment: Can you use `skip_before_filter` for `ItemsControllers#index`?

Comment: John, but the `respond_to { |f| f.html }` for `ItemsController#index` needs to be restricted to admins only.

Comment: @smotchkiss If it were me I think I'd take the pragmatic approach and add a new unrestricted collection route to `ItemsController` for the JavaScript.

Comment: John Topley, can you elaborate on that a little bit? I'm not sure what a "collection" route is.